Porque el modulo MTCN no funciona cuando convierto mi programa en un .exe Python
Cuando pruebo mi programa desde el codigo funciona correctamente, pero cuando lo convierto a ejecutable no reconoce el mtcn.
Aqui esta mi codigo y la lo que me presenta.



No concozco el paquete, pero el archivo que te falta es un archivo de datos (el modelo) que es parte del paquete MTCN y que se instala con él, pero al no ser parte del código fuente Pyinstaller no lo incluirá.  Agregalo explicitamente mediante PyInstaller.utils.hooks.collect_data_files o la opción --collec-data.

Por cierto, te doy la bienvenida a [es.so]. Una cosita, agrega siempre el código y los errores como texto, no como imagenes. Las imagenes dificultan la legibilidad (especialmente en dispositivos móviles), impiden que el código se pueda copiar y pegar para facilitar la reproducción por parte de quien quiera contestar y no indexa para búsquedas futuras. Simplemente copialo, lo pegas en la pregunta , lo seleccionas todo y luego pulsas Ctrl + k o el botón {} del editor para que quede formateado adecuadamente.

Muchas gracias, me funcionó con el --collec-data

El archivo que te falta (mtcnn_weights.npy) es parte del paquete mtcnn y se instala con él en la carpeta data localizada en la ruta de instalación del paquete en tu sistema.
PyInstaller sigue el sistema de imports para saber que paquetes y módulos debe incluir en el ejecutable, el problema es que ese archivo no es código como tal sino un recurso, el modelo en concreto.
Como no es importado, sino que es manejado como un archivo cualquiera, y dado que  PyInstaller no sigue la pista de estos archivos automáticamente, no lo incluye en el ejecutable final, por lo que tienes el esperado FileNotFoundError cuando se intanta abrir.
La solución en estos casos es decirle a PyInstaller de forma explícita que incluya esos archivos. Lo puedes hacer de dos formas:

Usando la opción --collect-data NOMBRE_DEL_MÓDULO en la linea de comandos al invocar pyinstaller para que cree el ejecutable. Si solo necesitas retocar esto, quizás es la opción más rápida y sencilla.
$ pyinstaller example.py --collec-data mtcnn ...


Usar PyInstaller.utils.hooks.collect_data_files().
Esto se puede hacer en un hook o en el .spec directamente pasando la salida a Analysis mediante su argumento datas:
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_data_files


# ...
datas = []
# ...
datas += collect_data_files('mtcnn')

a = Analysis(
    # ...
    datas=datas
)

# ...

coll = COLLECT(
    exe,
    a.binaries,
    a.zipfiles,
    a.datas,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    name='ejemplo',
)

Esto es lo que ocurre realmente al usar --collect-data pero tiene mucha más flexibilidad y permite mucho más control que la opción, de ser necesario.


